# Instantiate based on 4 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zxing, arcore

I'm zxing to estimate the 4 corner points of the QR Code. Following is my code to estimate the corner points.

```
LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(barcodeBitmap,QRTexture.width, QRTexture.height);
var options = new DecodingOptions { PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE }, TryHarder = true };
this.reader = new BarcodeReader(null, null, ls => new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(ls)) { AutoRotate = false, TryInverted = false, Options = options };
Result result = this.reader.Decode(source);
```

This gives me a result points which has the four corners of the QR Code. How do I overlay a 3D object over the qr code based on the position of these corner points?

Comment: An object has four properties 1) Top 2)  Left 3) Width 4) Height.  The QR corners have an XY cordinate  where you would set the Upper Left QR point to the Top/Left property of the object and scale as need base of the Width and Height.  You may want to add additional margins to the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that QR reader you are using but generally you basically only need 3 points e.g.

```
A-------B
|
|   X
|
C
```

X is where you want to place your object

So simply at

```
// Assuming given values
Vector3 A; // top-left corner
Vector3 B; // top-right corner
Vector3 C; // bottom-left corner
GameObject obj;

var vectorAtoB = B - A;
var vectorAtoC = C - A;
obj.transform.position = A + vectorAtoB * 0.5f + vectorAtoC * 0.5f;
```

---

and then you also need the orientation for your object. Depending on your needs of course but the easiest way is to set the object's [`Transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) and [`Transform.right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html) (it is enough to set two axis as the third one will be correct automatically)

```
var vectorCtoA;
obj.transform.forward = vectorCtoA;
obj.transform.right = vectorAtoB;
```

---

If you also need the scale then it gets tricky - or well at least you need one given value more:

```
// This is the expected QR code edge length
// if the QR code has exactly this size then the model will have scale 1,1,1
// otherwise it is scaled according to the QR code size    
float normalSize;

var qrEdgeLength = vectorAtoB.magnitude;
obj.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * qrEdgeLength / normalSize;
```

Comment: thank you!.. I'm using ZXing to read the qr code. It gives us the 2D coordinates (Vector2) and not the (Vector3). How do determine the Vector3 A, Vector3 B and Vector3 C from these 2D image coordinates that are obtained via zxing?

Comment: @user1241241 I would assume the 2D coordinates you get are in the camera pixel space? ... in that case it will be very tricky if you don't know exactly how far away from the camera the qr code is placed .... Since I don't know the library you are using .. do you have any documentation link about exactly what it returns as result?

Comment: From the [Demo](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Clients/UnityDemo/Assets/BarcodeCam.cs) they can get only the text .. not any position data out of it .. only in the Display plane via pixel positions .. but that is not enough data to actually get 3D space coordinates ... **Except** you know beforehand the exact size of the QR code so you could recalculate the 3D position using its perspective stretch etc .. but that is far from trivial or the scope of this forum

Comment: yes! I'm using zxing to determine the QR Code. Please check this repo that has the code and the documentation https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net

Comment: It is also possible to detect the 2D Coordinates. At the moment I'm manually calculating the pose through the mention that you've mentioned but as we know, pnp is a tough numerical problem and at times becomes unstable. thank you!